# Debian Testing: Network manager GUI not managing ethernet device

Tags: networkmanager

`> nmcli device`:

```
DEVICE  TYPE      STATE      CONNECTION 
eno1    ethernet  unmanaged  --         
lo      loopback  unmanaged  --
```

Then I run `sudo nmcli dev set eno1 managed yes`. But still it's in *unmanaged* state??

How do I change it to manage? Also Note:

```
cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=false
```

Should this be `true`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should *not* simply change `managed=false` to `managed=true` or you will probably get two competing tools managing the same interface.

As [described in Debian's wiki for NetworkManager](https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkManager):

> [Wired Networks are Unmanaged](https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkManager#Wired_Networks_are_Unmanaged)
>
> As of Debian 6.0 "Squeeze", NetworkManager does not manage any
> interface defined in /etc/network/interfaces by default.
>
> Unmanaged devices means NetworkManager doesn't handle those network
> devices. This occurs when two conditions are met:
>
> The file `/etc/network/interfaces` contains anything about the interface, even:
>
> ```
> allow-hotplug eth0
> iface eth0 inet dhcp
> ```
>
> And `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` contains:
>
> ```
> [main]
> plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
>
> [ifupdown]
> managed=false
> ```

So you just have to remove/comment out a part of the configuration in `/etc/network/interfaces` (or in a file in `/etc/network/interfaces.d/`) to have [*NetworkManager*](https://packages.debian.org/testing/network-manager) handle it instead of [*ifupdown*](https://packages.debian.org/testing/ifupdown) if it's not enough for your needs.

You should do this:

- do actions locally (not remotely through network) or you will lose access during reconfiguration
- run `ifdown eno1` to have *ifupdown* in a correct state before removing the configuration
- remove or comment out the entries in `/etc/network/interfaces...` having `auto eno1` or `allow-hotplug eno1` and the whole block starting with `iface eno1` (which might just be a single line with DHCP as in the wiki example) .
- keep NetworkManager's configuration unchanged
- run `systemctl restart NetworkManager` to have NetworkManager detect the configuration change

  In my tests, just doing `nmcli connection reload` was not enough to detect this configuration change. A complete restart was needed. NetworkManager should automatically create an entry for the wired network connection provided by `eno1` upon this restart. Else you'll have to create it yourself.

Comment: Nice.. I can now manage it through my gnome applet... thanks!

Comment: It's possible `nmcli general reload conf` instead of restarting NetworkManager would be enough (I didn't know about `general` then)